# Create html tags using JQuery

Tags: jquery, tags

I need to create option tags inside a select tag using JQuery,

this is the select tag:

```
<select id="tickets-room" style="height: 20px; width:200px; display: inline-block; margin-top:30px;" onchange="refreshRooms(this.value);">
</select>
```

Each option tag need an ID like 1,2,3,4

Each option tag should recieve "resp[].key" as it text.

I don't know if it makes sense, but i don't know how to explain it very well, this is the code i have with some of the elements i need. resp.key is the name i need as a text inside option tags, resp.value is an url i need to place on a button outside the select tag.

```
function refreshRooms(city){
    $.ajax('/services/tickets/<%= movieId %>?city=' + city).done(
        function(resp){
            alert(resp.length);
            console.log(resp[0].key + " " + resp[0].value); 
        }
    );      
}
```

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
function refreshRooms(city){
    $.ajax('/services/tickets/<%= movieId %>?city=' + city).done(
        function(resp){
            var sel = $("#tickets-room");

            for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                sel.append('<option value="' + resp[i].key + '">' + resp[i].value + '</option>');
            }
        }
    );      
}
```

Comment: This approch will add only the first element of the ajax request. Must interate

Comment: @Roger I'll really appreciate if you take off your downvote now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function refreshRooms(city){
    var jqTickers = $('#tickets-room');
    $.ajax('/services/tickets/<%= movieId %>?city=' + city)
        .done(function(resp){
            $.each(resp, function() {
                jqTickers.append($('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value + '</option>')
            });
        });
    });      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make new elements using the following syntax:

```
$('<option></option>');
```

This element however resides nowhere. It hasn't been added to the DOM, so it isn't visible. You'll need to use the `append` method or the `appendTo` method for that. It would look something like:

```
$('#tickets-room').append( $('<option></option>').attr( {'id':i,'value':resp[i].key} ).html( resp[i].key ) );
```

Comment: Thanks man, i used it inside a for event and works pretty good, only issue is, i need all the options to clear when i call refreshRoom again... How would i do it?

Comment: `$('#tickets-room').html( '' );` should do the trick (you simply overwrite the html inside the tag with... well... nothing)

Comment: thanks man, i did it using ().remove();... now could u help me with one last thing? i have a button that needs to go to a specifc url given by resp[i].value... is it possible?

Comment: If you understand the code above, you should have no trouble making it ;-)

Comment: i put the url in each option's value element, i just don't know how to make the button goes to the selected options url... =/